# How would you implement a functional programming language?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, implementation

In functional paradigm, a function is a primary 'control structure'. For eg., the `+` operator is also treated as a function and you can pass them around like any other 'objects'. I was wondering that if i had to implement a toy functional language, would i implement simple functions as true functions (i.e. translate `+` into a callable routine) or translate them into normal instructions that would be placed 'inline' into the translated code. But then, with the second strategy, would i be able to pass them around and apply them partially like in haskell? What are your thoughts on implementing/translating functions as a central idea in a functional language?

Comment: Something like this, I'd imagine: http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/

Comment: If you wanted to implement a toy functional language from scratch I would recommend you follow the advice here: * http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Papers/pj-lester-book/ If you wanted to reuse the Haskell run-time I would recommend starting here: * http://www.grabmueller.de/martin/www/pub/Transformers.en.html

Comment: The second strategy is known as defunctionalization: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defunctionalization

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend the PJL book. I wrote a compiler with help from it (in 1989-90, in Prolog) and the book is a very good introduction to the subject.

It might be dated (written in 1987, 30 years ago) but it still covers the basics very well. It is, however, completely focused on lazy languages like Haskell. At the time Haskell did not exist and the book uses LML or Miranda, a predecessor language but the languages are very close.